# Jquery populate multiple select boxes with the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I am dynamically creating  elements with javascript that end up looking something like this:

```
<select id="splitUserDDL" name="splitUserDDL[]"></select>
```

When I attempt to add options, it seems that the first select box is being populated but not the rest.  Is there a way that I can add the same options to all of the select boxes?

```
    $('#splitUserDDL').empty();
    var userDDL = document.getElementById('splitUserDDL');
    var defaultoption = document.createElement('option');
    defaultoption.text = '-Select-';
    defaultoption.value = 0;
    userDDL.add(defaultoption);
```

Comment: Do they all have the same `id`? If they do, that's invalid HTML and your exact problem. Also, why are you creating a 'label' `option`, rather than using an [`<optgroup>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) with a `label` attribute?

Comment: Elements need to have unique IDs. `document.getElementById` just returns the first match.

Comment: try   $('#splitUserDDL').append(defaultoption);

Comment: instead of `id="splitUserDDL"` use `class="splitUserDDL"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class instead of ID.

```
<select class="splitUserDDL" name="splitUserDDL[]"></select>
```

Then use jQuery to add the option, and loop over all of them:

```
$(".splitUserDDL").empty();
$(".splitUserDDL").each(function() {
    $(this).append($("<option>", {
        text: "-Select-",
        value: 0
    });
});
```